# Do single and array global operators do the same thing?

Tags: c++

In Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ book, in the item 12 - Writing Exception-Safe Code—Part 5, the author uses the global operators new and delete (single) rather than the global operators new[] and delete[] to allocate memory for an array without calling the default constructors.

My question is : why doesn't he call the array version of the operators if it's to create an array? The same thing applies for the destructors. See my variables `test1` and `test2` below.

If both global operators new and new[] do the same thing with the same parameters, then I don't understand why both exist, if it's not for semantic correctness.

The following pieces of code are taken from the book :

```
...
template <class T>
StackImpl<T>::StackImpl( size_t size )
    : v_( static_cast<T*>
            ( size == 0
            ? 0
            : operator new(sizeof(T)*size) ) ),
    vsize_(size),
    vused_(0)
{
} 

template <class T>
StackImpl<T>::~StackImpl()
{
    destroy( v_, v_+vused_ ); // this can't throw
    operator delete( v_ );
}
...

// construct() constructs a new object in
// a given location using an initial value
//
template <class T1, class T2>
void construct( T1* p, const T2& value )
{
    new (p) T1(value);
}

// destroy() destroys an object or a range
// of objects
//
template <class T>
void destroy( T* p )
{
    p->~T();
}

template <class FwdIter>
void destroy( FwdIter first, FwdIter last )
{
    while( first != last )
    {
        destroy( &*first );
        ++first;
    }
}
```

I didn't fully understand it at first, so I did a little test :

```
struct OperatorTest
{
    OperatorTest()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~OperatorTest()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    OperatorTest&  operator=(const OperatorTest& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Operator new[]
    OperatorTest* test1 = static_cast<OperatorTest*>(operator new[](sizeof(OperatorTest) * 5)); // Only allocate memory
    new (&test1[0]) OperatorTest(); // Calls the constructor by doing a placement new
    test1[0].~OperatorTest(); // Calls the destructor
    operator delete[](test1);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Operator new
    OperatorTest* test2 = static_cast<OperatorTest*>(operator new(sizeof(OperatorTest) * 5)); // Only allocate memory
    new (&test2[0]) OperatorTest(); // Calls the constructor by doing a placement new
    test2[0].~OperatorTest(); // Calls the destructor
    operator delete(test2);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
        // How does the STL allocate memory?
        std::vector<OperatorTest> test3{ 3 }; // Allocate memory and calls the default constructor
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Manual new[] / delete[]
    OperatorTest* test4 = new OperatorTest[3];
    delete[] test4;

    return 0;
}
```

The results of the main function in console is :

1. Constructor
2. Destructor
3. Constructor
4. Destructor
5. Constructor
6. Constructor
7. Constructor
8. Destructor
9. Destructor
10. Destructor
11. Constructor
12. Constructor
13. Constructor
14. Destructor
15. Destructor
16. Destructor

Both global single and array operators seem to work to allocate memory for an array.

Comment: "My question is : why doesn't he call the array version of the operators if it's to create an array?" because he wants to allocate raw memory to store objects later rather than create array of existing objects.

Comment: I meant like the variables `test1` in my code.

Comment: @eukaryota Thanks, I totally forgot